# Import csv file into an ms access table- Data ignored

Tags: ms-access

Using this below query to import a csv file into a new table

```
SELECT * into tbl1 FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;DATABASE=filepath].[filename.csv]
```

after importing some data is not imported. The reason is it sets the max length for columns based on the first few records. How can i ensure the data is imported correctly. The columns are dynamic. So i cannot define the table first and then import. Any other work arounds are greatly appreciated.

Is there any option available in the select syntax?

Comment: The answer in the given post partially answers my question . ie to create a temporary table. so i create a temp table based on the data. then create actual table with enough column length . then Load from temp to actual table